# Is setting up listeners inside redux action creators a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am building an app where it constantly listens to location changes and updates the store. I am wondering if it is a good idea to place my listeners inside my action creator instead of the component itself.

For instance,

```js
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.watchLocation();
}

// inside action creator
export function watchLocation() {
  LocationManager.on("location", location => {
    dispatchLocationlocation);
  });
}
```

Or instead, inside my react-native component,

```js
componentWillMount() {
  LocationManager.on("location", location => {
    // call action to dispatch location updates
  });
}
```

What are the differences in terms of performance, if I place my listeners inside my action creators?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, I don't think it makes much of a difference, but I would disagree with Varun's answer regarding the placement of your listeners. If you create such an action and dispatch it once, you need an extra action to update the store (sure, you can use thunk for that), and it might be difficult to later disable the callback, as you lose access to the callback reference, since it is only used in the action call. If you use the componentDidMount/componentWillUnmount lifecycle methods to track your event handlers, it is easy to avoid memory leaks. By the way, do not use componentWillMount for anything that could cause side effects:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

See the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) for more information.

Comment: Why do you need an extra action? What if you don't put any?

In case of periodic jobs, If you need to disable it later, you could trigger an action to store the timer id in the store (if you use setInterval), and later on disable it with another action. or in the case of that API, you probably don't need to store anything, I guess there is a method LocationManager.stopWatching.

I like the comment from Varun about having your code more extendable, modular, and remove all the logic from the component (which only shows stuff).

Comment: Because you need an action to start listening and another one that really goes into the reducers. You are right in that you can store timer ids in a store, but since they will most likely be bound to the lifecycle of a component, I would consider it a bit overkill (creating actions for enabling/disabling, setting up a reducer for it), and taking care of dispatching the actions in the right places, which in the end will most likely be the componentDidMount/componentWillUnmount methods anyway.

Comment: Also, a lot of libraries do not handle your callbacks for you, think for instance of an event listener that can take n callbacks (a simple addEventListener, for example). How do you tell removeEventListener which callback you want to stop using? Your only choice is the reference to the callback function. Also, in terms of modularity it remains pretty much the same, have an action to update values in the store, and two extra lines in a component to track a callback that dispatches updates.

Comment: ok agree for overkill, it's right, it's most likely bound to lifecycle of component. and agree with eventListener (even thougth I've been using none in the past 3 months, so didn't face it).

Still why do you need at all cost to have a paired action that goes in the reducer in that specific case? Nothing forces you (I have very similar actions which do not dispatch any action straight away), and it's still coherent since it will dispatch an action at some point.

Comment: Yes Martin you're correct ok having the need of extra actions to dispatch the data and I'm ok with that. In fact, my app consists of several other methods that need those extra method alone, so I guess I'm live with this setup, if there's no performance drawback.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference in performance if you set up the listeners in an action creator or the component itself but I think it is a good idea to set them up in the action creators because you can easily access current state in an action creator (using redux-thunk or some other package) and allows the code to be more extendable.